# access a pointer struct into a struct

Tags: c, struct

I thought this is a simple question but I can not understand it. I have the following code:

```
int main(int argv,char **argc){
  typedef struct tag{
    int c;
    float x;
    struct tag *s_ptr;
  } utag;

  utag mytag;

  mytag.(&s_ptr->c)=10;
  printf("%d",mytag.s_ptr->c);
  return 0;
}
```

I try to access the variables of the nested struct. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please format your question so that it's readable.  Thanks.

Comment: What makes you say something is wrong?

Comment: What is the intent of `mytag.(&s_ptr->c)=10;`?  Does that compile?

Comment: The above won't even compile. What does `mytag.(&s_ptr->c)` mean?

Comment: In your variable `mytag`, you've not initialized the pointer to point to anything, so (once you get the code compiling; use `mytag.s_ptr->c` as the notation), you are accessing indeterminate memory.  You always need to know where a pointer is pointing - and that it is pointing somewhere useful.  For example: `mytag.s_ptr = &mytag; mytag.c = 42;` then you could run the `printf()` statement.

Comment: `utag other; mytag.s_ptr = &other; mytag.s_ptr->c = 10; printf("%d\n", mytag.s_ptr->c);`

Answer (score 1):

Try

> (mytag.s_ptr)->c = 10;

s_ptr is a pointer, but utag is declared (it's a struct, not a pointer to a struct).  "mytag.s_ptr" gets you to a pointer to another "tag" struct, '->' dereferences the pointer and the final 'c' identifies the item within the struct you want.

HOWEVER, since you never set s_ptr to anything your code, as is, will crash, you need to initialize mytag.s_ptr to a valid tag struct.

Comment: The parentheses are unnecessary.

Comment: I'm not going to ding you about it, but I don't think they help because they're unusual and unnecessary.  I was trying to think where they might help, and outside of extreme cases like `(*function)(arg1)->member` (calling a function via a pointer to function, old-school notation, and using the returned pointer to structure, where there might be some merit to cleaning up, but just parentheses are probably not the best answer even then), they really aren't necessary. Using `.` and `->` is usually best done with no parentheses.  Trying to group other than left-to-right is meaningless, of course.